# Comparing Objective-C With Swift Arrays and NOT Operators

Tags: objective-c, swift

Are these pieces of code equivalent?

Objective C:

```
   if !someArray {
      // do something
   }
```

Swift:

```
   if someArray.isEmpty {
      // do something
   }
```

Comment: `if (!someArray)` in Objective-C is different from `if ([someArray count] == 0)`, but that depends on what you want to do/check.

Comment: This helps! Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, for a nil array, `[someArray count]` returns 0. However, a non-nil array could *also* have a 0 count, and the language itself doesn't strongly enforce that you differentiate between nil arrays and empty arrays. Swift requires you to make a distinction between empty arrays and nil arrays, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.

The Objective-C code checks whether the array exists or not. In other words, it checks if the array is `nil`.

The Swift code checks whether the array is empty or not.

To make sure that a Swift Array is not `nil`, you can use this:

```
if someArray != nil {
    print("The array is not nil")
}
```

Comment: Is there any shorthand version in Swift? Or should I just unwrap the array in swift to make sure it's not nil before that?

Comment: I get a warning saying "Comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to nil always returns true."

Comment: So your array is not optional, which means it can't be `nil` at all. Only optional values can be `nil`. You don't need to check if a non-optional value is `nil` or not because it's always not `nil`.

Comment: Okay great! I'm converting Objective C code to Swift. This makes sense! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `someArray` is defined as:

```
NSArray *someArray = @[@1, @2, @3];
```

then `if !someArray {` checks that the pointer is not zero, which is almost universally the same as check that the pointer is not `nil`. It makes no guarantees about the count of the array.